# Update an embedded document in a collection adding an element at the end

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo and I have a document in a collection that have a field that is an array of objects like this an example of document is this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("509df76fbcf1bf5b27b4a23e"), 
    "field1" : "asfasfdas", 
    "field2" : "asfasdfa", 
    "embedded" : [ 
       { "field1" : "asdfasdf", "field2" : "asdfasdfa" }, 
       { "field1" : "asdfasfth.", "field2" : "asdfasf" }
    ]
}
```

So I'd like to add a new object in the field `embedded`. What method can I use to achieve this?

Comment: [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) or [`update_many`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) depending on what you are trying to do. Also you need the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use update query and $push

```
db.collection.update({
    _id: "509df76fbcf1bf5b27b4a23e"
}, {
    $push: {
        embedded: {
            $each: [{
                "field1": "test1",
                "field2": "test1"
            } {
                "field1": "test2",
                "field2": "test2"
            }]
        }
    }
})
```